# Trouble with UICollectionViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have added another UICollectionViewCell onto my UICollectionView as shown:

[image: Storyboard Image]

Each are connected to a different class the Yellow one is connected to a class called ImageCell and the Blue one is connected to a class called TwitterCell. The Image Cell is supposed to Display an Instagram picture with the UIImageView (Which BTW works fine right now). However I want to add other cells under the TwitterCell which is supposed to show Twitter Tweets of the user with the UILabel. Here is my code right now:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell"
                                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSURL *url = [self imageUrlForEntryAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //NSLog(@"%@", url);
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    TwitterCell *tweetCell = (TwitterCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"twitterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    return cell;
    return tweetCell;
}
```

Here is the end image of what I want (keep in mind everything is ordered by time posted):

[image: Final Product Image]

Comment: You asked this question before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284955/how-would-you-add-two-different-uicollectionviewcells), and apparently haven't made any attempt to change your code based on my answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier`: in order to get the dequeue to work properly.  Also, you can only answer one cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath:  check to see if the row is even or odd to decide which kind of cell to dequeue, then initialize the contents only of that cell.

Comment: could you show me how to construct the code to check if the row is even or odd

Comment: If `indexPath.row % 2 == 0`, the row is even.